# .Net core request filtering and file downloads

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications

We have an .net core Web application which simply hosts files for some of our client applications updates.

We decided to add Application insights in one of these client applications, and the file ApplicationInsights.config is a part of update.

The request to https://server/path/to/update/ApplicationInsights.config throws 404 error.

So far I’ve tried :

1. Add “.config” extension in static files definition on the startup : no effect (This worked for .exe and .dll)
2. Enable folder browsing for this folder, still no effect

It seems to be related to some out-of-box requests filtering.

The question is :

How do I disable all download restriction on a specific folder (Best)

OR

How do I disable ALL filtering for *.config files

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the default [`FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/0cd79cc4c174300e9aa07f73ff2b167a0d464d34/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs#L18-L399) doesn't provide a mapping for `*.config` files.

To make it serve `*.config` files, simply create your own `ContentTypeProvider`, or add mapping for `*.config` :

```
var myContentTypeProvider= new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
myContentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".config","text/plain");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions{
    RequestPath = "/path/to/update",
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"path/to/update"),
        ExclusionFilters.None
    ),
    ContentTypeProvider = myContentTypeProvider,
});
```

**[Update]**

After a discussion, the following `Web.Config` ( by OP) works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <remove fileExtension=".config" /> 
                    <add fileExtension=".config" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering> 
        </security> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: @itiminus :  Hello and thank you, Unfortunately I’ve already tried this solution (As mentioned in the question). It works for every single file extension I’ve tried (.exe, .dll included), but NOT with .config. 
The error message talks about configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/fileExtensions section in web.config. We don’t have web.config for this app.

Comment: @Jurion How did you try this solution? Could you please show us the code? I'm asking this because my code works flawlessly for me.

Comment: hello @itminus, here is a screen shot : 1st exactlly your solution (Throws folder not found exception). 2d : used dfefault filesprovider with adjusted mappings. Works for .exe and .dll. Edit : link https://imgur.com/a/9vSOTJI

Comment: @Jurion 1. What's the Current Directory when you run this website ? 2. Does the `AutoUpdates/ApplicationInsights.config` file exist ? 3. Are you serving the statics files under the root path ? There's no `RequestPath`

Comment: @Jurion are your kestrel behind a proxy server such as Nginx or IIS ?

Comment: The static files are in wwwroot. It's a default IIS express for testing and Azure WebApp for production. There is no proxies of any kind. GetCurrentDirectory points to sources of the project directory.

Comment: @Jurion Although the Kestrel can return the file streams as expected, IIS won't allow download `*.config` files by default. We need also to config the web.config .

Comment: well, I guess I'll need to patch the updater and just put everything in a ZIP. This is what I wanted to avoid, but even Rewrite doesn't help :             var options = new RewriteOptions();
            options.AddRedirect("config$", "google");
            app.UseRewriter(options);
 still throws 404

Comment: @Jurion also that might walk around it, I believe [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions/#configuration-sample) will help solve this question. I'm now trying to reproduce the issue and will test the iis configuration laterly.

Comment: Thank you ! That worked. I didn't know I can just throw web.config in core application. Here is web.config : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <remove fileExtension=".config" />
          <add fileExtension=".config" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration> Edit : for some reason I can't use "@" in comments. Edit 2 : /web.config stays protected from acces, which is good